# Over-engineered fizzbuzz

Tags: haskell, fizzbuzz, fibonacci-sequence

I've got this fizzbuzz project I am using for a blog series, among other things. In this version, the fizzbuzz function is fed from a Fibonacci generator. I'm particularly concerned with the efficiency of the Fibonacci generator, but all scrutiny is welcomed.

[Here is a link to the entire project](https://github.com/mlitchard/swiftfizz/tree/9102ed664822043cf26290de43eff6a5c4281335), but below are the parts I think would be sufficient to spot trouble with how I am generating Fibonacci numbers.

```
-- Driver function performs following
-- (1) checks that input is proper
-- (2) creates integer list for fibonacci generator
-- (3) calculates first x in fibonnaci sequence
-- (4) generates fizzbuzz output using (3)

fizzBuzzFib :: [Text] -> Either FizzError [Text]
fizzBuzzFib str =
mapM fizzbuzz          =<<
mapM fibb              =<< -- Possible problem here
(\x -> Right [1 .. x]) =<<
convertToPInt          =<<
mustHaveOne str

fibb :: Integer -> Either FizzError Integer
fibb n = Right $ snd . foldl' fib' (1, 0) . map (toEnum . fromIntegral) $ unfoldl divs n
  where
    unfoldl f x =
      case f x of
        Nothing     -> []
        Just (u, v) -> unfoldl f v ++ [u]

    divs 0 = Nothing
    divs k = Just (uncurry (flip (,)) (k `divMod` 2))

    fib' (f, g) p
      | p = (f*(f+c*g), f^c + g^c)
      | otherwise = (f^c+g^c, g*(c*f-g))
      where
        c :: Integer -- See codebase for reasons
        c = 2
```

Comment: The title says fizzbuzz, but the contents says Fibonacci. Also, you should at least include the types of your functions in your driver, otherwise it's hard to check the reason behind them.

Comment: It's been almost two years. Do you want to [edit] your post or review it yourself?